# Negative coordinates in C# Graphics?

Tags: c#, graphics

I am following [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Drawing_Graphics_DrawString_System_String_System_Drawing_Font_System_Drawing_Brush_System_Single_System_Single_), specifically the DrawString method. It says that
for

```
public void DrawString (string s, System.Drawing.Font font, System.Drawing.Brush brush, float x, float y);
```

x and y are the coordinates of the upper-left corner of the drawn text.

I have call this function with x=0 but there is still some space between the border and the upper left corner so I call it with x=-10 and now it is touching the border.

Does this mean that somehow we can call these with negative values?

Comment: Yes, you can move the drawing into the negative. In fact you can move the whole graphics canvas there by Graphics.TranslateTransform(-x, -y);

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Depending upon how the Font was developed every character has a bounding box. The Top-Left cordinates that you specify are not where the Alphabet starts but are from where the Bounding Box Top-left starts.

In this image it will be the Top-left Corner of the black rectangle. Now depending upon the Font/Typography - Either the Actual alphabet will be very closely aligned with the bounding box boundaries or may have some padding (like my poor example below has quite some space).

Thats why in your case -10 makes it look like as if Character/Alphabet starts from Exact edge. But In realtiy the Bounding Box Top-Left is at -10 (negative cordinate) which is why it looks so.

Comment: A post that contains the word 'Typography' shouldn't be so short on line feeds ;-)

Comment: :) That was a quick reply - though not enough reason for bad formatting :D